# Matplotlib: displaying only unique labels for the legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have an array of X (X.shape = [N, 2]) and labels (labels.shape = N).
I want to produce a scatter of X[:,0], X[:,1], color corresponding to the label, and only the unique labels displayed.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set(context='poster', style='dark')

X = rand(500)
Y = rand(500)
labels = np.round(rand(500)*4).astype(int)
print(np.unique(labels)) # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

plt.scatter(X, Y, c=labels, cmap='rainbow') # this does what I want minus the labels

plt.scatter(X, Y, c=labels, cmap='rainbow', label=labels)
plt.legend(loc='best') # this produces 500 labels instead of 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could plot each label individually. You need to choose its color from the `cmap`, which you need to normalize to your labels first.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set(context='poster', style='dark')

X = rand(500)
Y = rand(500)
labels = np.round(rand(500)*4).astype(int)
unique_labels=np.unique(labels) # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=unique_labels[0], vmax=unique_labels[-1])
m = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.rainbow)

for label in np.unique(labels):
    color = m.to_rgba(label)
    plt.scatter(X[labels==label], Y[labels==label], c=color, label=label)

plt.legend(loc='best')
```

produces this (without `seaborn`, as I don't have that installed, but you get the idea):
[image]